# Changes in TemplateApply/StringTemplate in V11

Tags: bugs, hold, templates

**Bug introduced in V11.0.0 and fixed in V11.2**

> [CASE:3821295]

---

It seems that in v11+ arguments are not injected into held `StringTemplate`, in contrary to how it behaved earlier.

In 10.4

```
ReleaseHold @ TemplateApply[
  Hold @ StringTemplate["``"],
  {"test"}
]
```

> ```
> "test"
> ```

in 11.0.1

> ```
> TemplateObject[{TemplateSlot[1]}, InsertionFunction -> TextString, 
>   CombinerFunction -> StringJoin
> ] 
>   (*this is what StringTemplate["``"] evaluates to*)
> ```

Documentation does not contain any notes about updates so I consider it a bug. The more that `ReleaseHold@TemplateApply[Hold@TemplateSlot[1], {"test"}]` works well (that is documented).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regardeless whether it is a bug I need an old behavior for compatibility reasons. My fix is to inject evalauted `StringTemplate` because `TemplateObject` will be handled correctly.

```
ReleaseHold @ TemplateApply[
  Hold @ StringTemplate["``"] /. s_StringTemplate :> RuleCondition[s],
  {"test"}
]
```